# Login control doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, authentication

i try to login with the login control, but it doesn't let me, it doesn't allow me to reset a password, but does allow to retrieve a password:

Here is my configuration file:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp from="user@example.com">
        <network host="smtp.example.com"  enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="false" port="587" userName="user@example.com" password="password"/>
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="YourGuruDB" connectionString="Data Source=DIMA-00AA1DA557;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True"/>
    <add name="modelConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DIMA-00AA1DA557;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer2" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="MyLocalSQLServer" connectionString="Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;data source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
  </connectionStrings>

<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="MyMembershipProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
            minRequiredPasswordLength="2"         
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1000"
            passwordAttemptWindow="1000"
            applicationName="/WebSite10"  />
    </providers>
</membership>   
<roleManager enabled="true" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH"  loginUrl="~/Registration.aspx"
     defaultUrl="default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/"
     requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true"
     cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" domain=""
     enableCrossAppRedirects="false">
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1" />
  </forms>
</authentication>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to add something to your credetials line:

```
<credentials passwordFormat="SHA1" />
```

Add User and Password credentials like this:

```
<credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
  <user name="user" password="ca064d0730abfeb09e383a0e82e65f73"/>
</credentials>
```

**Edit:** You can check if User and PW are valid like this:

```
If FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(tb_user.Text, tb_pw.Text) Then
   'is valid!'

   'then do stuff like'
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tb_user.Text, False)
End If
```

Comment: Where does that credential go? and will it make the login control work?

Comment: i know that i can, but i dont want to do it programatically, only via the controls!!!!